# HTML/CSS Missing Link Tags?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ide

I wanted to make a circle cursor and I copied the code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/clementGir/pen/RQqvQx)

I am working in another IDE called Repl.it and so I copied the exact same code from codepen to repl.it (Note: I did use the correct code from codepen by compiling it first)

The code is not working in [repl.it](https://replit.com/join/zntiudyjki-hussainomer1)

I am not sure what I am missing, but I am pretty sure it has to do with the tags. Any help would be much appreciated.

My Output:

[The cursor stays at the top left and does not move at all for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsObR.png)

This is the code:

```js
const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverable');

// Listeners
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
}

// Move the cursor
window.CP.exitedLoop(0);function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
    x: e.pageX - 15,
    y: e.pageY - 15 });

  TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
    x: e.pageX - 5,
    y: e.pageY - 7 });

}

// Hover an element
function onMouseHover() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 4 });

}
function onMouseHoverOut() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 1 });

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #010101;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
}
body h1,
body p,
body a {
  color: #fff;
}
body a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
body .cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
body .cursor__ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
}
body .cursor__ball circle {
  fill: #f7f8fa;
}
body .left,
body .right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body .right {
  background: #fff;
}
body .right a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
body .right h1,
body .right p,
body .right a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
    <svg height="30" width="30">
      <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
    <svg height="10" width="10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="left">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Check out this link:</p>
  <a class="hoverable">Hover meh</a>  
</div>

<div class="right">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Check out this link:</p>
  <a class="hoverable">Hover meh</a>  
</div>
```

The code does not work here either, there is something that I am missing but not quite sure, could you please help?

Comment: Running the snippet gives errors - have you looked at them, and is there a missing library or chunk of code?

Comment: Yeah thats what I can't figure out, because its the exact same code from codepen

Comment: I don't see all the JS sources that are loaded in the codepen in your snippet. tweenmax for example. Use your browser devtools on the codepen and look carefully at everything in the header and the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with your html file.. I checkout Codepen and got compiled css and js code.
you also have to link js lib for this, as I told before, issue is in your html file.

below is the working code
enjoy !!

Mark as approved would be appreciated :)

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #010101;
    cursor: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    font-family: monospace;
}

body h1, body p, body a {
    color: #fff;
}

body a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

body .cursor {
    pointer-events: none;
}

body .cursor__ball {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 1000;
}

body .cursor__ball circle {
    fill: #f7f8fa;
}

body .left, body .right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

body .right {
    background: #fff;
}

body .right a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

body .right h1, body .right p, body .right a {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Circle Cursor</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="cursor">
        <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
            <svg height="30" width="30">
                <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>

        <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
            <svg height="10" width="10">
                <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>Check out this link:</p>
        <a class="hoverable">Hover meh</a>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>Check out this link:</p>
        <a class="hoverable">Hover meh</a>
    </div>

</body>

<script>
    const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
    const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
    const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverable');

    // Listeners
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
        $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
        $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
    }

    // Move the cursor
    function onMouseMove(e) {
        TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
            x: e.pageX - 15,
            y: e.pageY - 15
        })
        TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
            x: e.pageX - 5,
            y: e.pageY - 7
        })
    }

    // Hover an element
    function onMouseHover() {
        TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
            scale: 4
        })
    }
    function onMouseHoverOut() {
        TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
            scale: 1
        })
    }
</script>

</html>
```